# Searching careers gives results in different city and country

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

If you search careers for "Houston, TX" (any job filter, or no filter), you get results for Treuddyn, United Kingdom.

If you search for "Houston" (no "TX"), it gives correct results (Jobs in Houston, TX).
If you search for "Austin, TX", it also gives the correct results (Jobs in Austin, TX).

Comment: Yep. Looks like Houston is broken. I'll se if we can get that fixed for you.

Comment: Houston, we have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue today [Career search goes to Fort Hood Tx](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196786/231173) and it was pointed out to me that this bug was never responded to. The Houston search was fixed shortly after the issue was reported. Hopefully you noticed already. Our apologies for the delay.