# Career search goes to Fort Hood Tx

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

We are looking for Test/Qa people in Vancouver

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=test&location=vancouver
Responds with

> 0 jobs for “test” near Fort Hood, TX

I thought is was just the search term **TEST** but the same behaviour occurs for any keyword

Adding a province (or even a state) generates correct results
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=test&location=vancouver+bc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out to us. It has been fixed, and a search for "Vancouver" will now bring up results in Vancouver, BC as expected.

Comment: Thanks, and a big Nelson Muntz "haw haw" to Vancouver WA

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194474/223030

Comment: @michaelb958 You are correct that they are related issues. That one has been fixed for a while, but thank you for pointing out that it had gone unanswered.